# A project task/issue in GitHub Projects still shows open even though the issue has been closed

Tags: github, github-issues, github-projects

The Project board for my repo shows an open issue in the project even though the issue is actually closed. The filter for the board is set to show only open issues. Is this a bug, or did I make a mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce this problem, but I found a workaround...

I reopened the issue that was causing the problem, then closed it with a comment. Now it is filtered out of the project view!